# How to provide a configuration file provision while building a react component library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rollup

The React component library should provide a provision to the consuming project to pass configuration file that the component library will use (either during build / runtime)

The configuration file might contain primary, secondary Colors, typography details. (Similiar to how Tailwind has tailwind.config.js)

How do I create this in React JS ?

Here is the component library that I've built so far: https://github.com/fyndreact/nitrozen

Any kind of direction would really help.

Answer (score 1):

The config is just a data file, you just need to write the correct path to it.

For example, you have compiled your project into a module that is imported somewhere else and has the following structure:

[Try it live](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-worker-lxxlkl?file=/src/App.js)

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
│  ├─ myLib/
│  │  ├─ index.js
├─ src/
│  ├─ index.css
│  ├─ index.js
├─ myLib.config.js
```

myLib.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  "test": 1
}
```

my-app/node_modules/myLib/index.js

```
const myConfig = require('../../myLib.config.js')

console.log(myConfig)
```

So in your library you will be able to see this config as `js` object.
You can also make the file path dynamic for more flexibility

Answer (score 0):

you can read this doc
https://dev.to/alexeagleson/how-to-create-and-publish-a-react-component-library-2oe
thank you

Comment: It is also good to provide your own solution and use the article you have posted as a reference